# Automated Integration Testing between two API's

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing

My solution consists of four main components:

- **MVC UI** - Calls Web API 1 (out of scope for this question)
- **Web API 1** - Calls Web API 2 and handles the response
- **Web API 2** - Calls database and handles the response
- **Database** - Stores data (out of scope for this question)

I'm looking into how to set up automation tests to verify the integration between these components. It seems fairly straight forward to test the integration between **Web API 2** and **Database**, following guides such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) or [this](https://adatis.co.uk/sql-server-database-integration-testing-using-nunit/), however I'm not sure how to go about verifying the integration between my two APIs.

How can I set up automated integration tests to verify the integration between **Web API 1** and **Web API 2**?

Answer (score 0):

Well the links you are posted are more than sufficient to test your API. You can start initialize both (probably in the constructor). You start both API's programmaticly and then set up your test with simple http requests. So basically your API's will be both up and running thus when you call API_1 it should make a call to API_2.

```
Call API_1 -> API_1 calls -> API_2
```

And another test would be to stimulate responses directly from API 1 to API 2 in order to test it directly.